# Can't download C4 documentation on Xcode 5

Tags: c4

just got the xcode 5, but it does not support the third party documentation any more.
so i download an app called " doc for xcode", it support to download the third party documentation and make it works on Xcode5, but i cannot find any source to download c4 doc file.

Comment: You should clarify the question and provide links to where you tried downloading these.

Comment: However, I've tested the installer on Xcode 5, with OSX 10.8... 

Are you able to replicate this? 

Just to confirm: every time you try to install the C4 templates, your able to see the C4 option in Xcode, but you're unable to view any C4 documentation from Xcode

Answer (score 1):

The docset for C4 can be found at :

[www.c4ios.com/installer/C4Docset.zip](http://www.c4ios.com/installer/C4Docset.zip)